# How to launch node debugging session when developing custom sfdx plugin

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, debugging, sfdx-plugin

Working with a friend on some pretty cool sfdx plugins. Challenge seems to be if something goes wrong I get a pretty generic error, no stack trace, and it's a real challenging tracing things back to where the error occurred.

Now, I wouldn't be a salesforce developer if I wasn't familiar with print debugging, which appears to be an option when you're developing custom plugins for sfdx. But seeing as the actual code is node for the most part it seems impossible there isn't a simple way to breakpoints and step through debugging.

Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Official documentation can be [found here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_debug.htm).

### However

I haven't had much success getting the debugger to hit breakpoints in my actual commands.  Even when I did get it to break, source-maps seemed to be way off.

To even get it to attach, I had to remove `"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"` from the `launch.json` config.  Otherwise I would get an error when trying to start the debugger:

> Both localRoot and remoteRoot must be specified

It might be that both `localRoot and remoteRoot` need to bet set.  I've tried several combinations without luck.

What has been helpful is setting env for `SFDX_ENV=development` and `NODE_ENV=development` so you can at least get stack traces.

---

**UPDATE**

Looks like there is now a [PR to fix this](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate/pull/58)... Please comment and express your support to get this fixed ASAP!

Comment: It's very disappointing.  When I first tried using the debugger to debug plugins it worked like a charm.   Sadly it appears completely broken now.